# Neo4jClient Cypher query collect statement with multiple values

Tags: c#, neo4j, neo4jclient

i'm trying to convert a query from cypher to use neo4jclient api in c#

Here is my cypher

```
start server=node:node_auto_index(serverId='SHO2K3MS49')
MATCH 
 server-[:IS_SERVER_TYPE]->type,
 appEnv-[:HAS_SERVER]->server,
 app-[:HAS_ENV]->appEnv
return        
   server.serverId,
   collect([
   appEnv.environmentTypeId,
   appEnv.appEnvId,
   app.appId,
   app.appName
  ]) ;
```

The query returns one line per server and collects all the applications on that server.

The .CollectAs api as far as i can see only allows single values.

An idea how to do this with the .net api?

**EDIT**

i've just tried this query

```
_connectedClient
 .Cypher                 
 .Start(new {server = Node.ByIndexLookup("node_auto_index", "serverId", "SHO2K3MS49") })
 .Match("server-[:IS_SERVER_TYPE]->type", "appEnv-[:HAS_SERVER]->server", "app-[:HAS_ENV]->appEnv")               
 .Return((server, appEnv, app) => 
  new
   {
       ServerName = Return.As<string>("server.serverId"),     
       aa = Return.As<dynamic>    ("collect([appEnv.environmentTypeId,appEnv.appEnvId,app.appId,app.appName])")                                                                                                                          
   })
 .Results;
```

and received this result.

**stacktrace**

```
at Neo4jClient.Serialization.CypherJsonDeserializer`1.Deserialize(String content)
   at Neo4jClient.GraphClient.<>c__DisplayClass1e`1.<Neo4jClient.IRawGraphClient.ExecuteGetCypherResultsAsync>b__1d(Task`1 responseTask)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
```

**innerexception**

```
Accessed JArray values with invalid key value: "data". Array position index expected
```

**message** -- removed boilerplate text for brevity

```
Neo4jClient encountered an exception while deserializing the response from the server. This is likely a bug in Neo4jClient.

Include the full type definition of <>f__AnonymousType1`2[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.Object, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].

Include this raw JSON, with any sensitive values replaced with non-sensitive equivalents:

{"columns":["ServerName","aa"],"data":[["SHO2K3MS49",[["PRD","MATT.PRD","MATT","MATT"],["PRD","ARCSERV.PRD","ARCSERV","ArcServ"],["PRD","ACTIVE DIRECTORY _WINDOWS SERVER NETWORKING_.PRD","ACTIVE DIRECTORY _WINDOWS SERVER NETWORKING_","Active Directory (Windows Server networking)"]]]]}
Parameter name: content
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because the results you bring back from the `collect` statement are basically strings with no defining columns. JSON.NET can't infer what the columns are (and you can't use `AS` to help it), so all you get are strings like:

```
"[\r\n"EnvType1",\r\n"AppEnvId1",\r\n"App2",\r\n"App 2"\r\n]"
```

Which you can get by using the following query:

```
_connectedClient
    .Cypher                 
    .Start(new {server = Node.ByIndexLookup("node_auto_index", "serverId", "SHO2K3MS49") })
    .Match("server-[:IS_SERVER_TYPE]->type", "appEnv-[:HAS_SERVER]->server", "app-[:HAS_ENV]->appEnv")               
     .Return((server, appEnv, app) => 
      new
       {
           ServerName = Return.As<string>("server.serverId"),     
           aa = Return.As<IEnumerable<string>>("collect([appEnv.environmentTypeId,appEnv.appEnvId,app.appId,app.appName])")                                                                                                                          
       })
     .Results;
```

*I've changed the return type for the `aa` property to be `IEnumerable<string>`.*

Another route would be to use `GroupBy` after getting the data:

```
var query2 = GraphClient
    .Cypher
    .Start(new { server = new NodeReference(1) })
    .Match("server-[:IS_SERVER_TYPE]->type", "appEnv-[:HAS_SERVER]->server", "app-[:HAS_ENV]->appEnv")
    .Return((server, appEnv, app) =>
        new
        {
            ServerId = Return.As<string>("server.ServerId"),
            EnvironmentTypeId = Return.As<string>("appEnv.EnvironmentTypeId"),
            AppEnvId = Return.As<string>("appEnv.AppEnvId"),
            AppId = Return.As<string>("app.AppId"),
            AppName = Return.As<string>("app.AppName"),
        });

var results2 = query2.Results.GroupBy(g => g.ServerId).ToList();
```

Which I think would give you the results in the way you want them, I guess at issue here is whether it's more performant to do the `collect` on the server, or to `GroupBy` on the client...